# Reference for Shankaracharya quote?

Tags: vedas, adi-shankaracharya

Does anyone have original reference and source for this quote?

"Shrutis are authorities only in the matter of things we cannot decide by our instruments. They tell us what is beyond knowledge, not for worldly matters."

Answer (score 2):

You maybe referring to [Śaṅkarācārya's commentary](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=ro&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=66&etgb=1&setgb=1&choose=1) on Bhagavad-gītā 18.66:

> As for the argument that (the figurative notion should be accepted) on the authority of the Vedas, we say, 'No', because their validity concerns unseen results. The validity of the Vedas holds good only with regard to matters concerning the relation between ends and means of Agnihotra etc., which are not known through such valid means of knowledge as direct perception; but not with regard to objects of direct perception etc., **because the validity of the Vedas lies in revealing what is beyond direct perception**.